# Divide array into chunks F#

Tags: f#

I am new to F# and I have to divide an array into 'n' chunks to  assign each chunk to an actor. Can anyone help me out with a function to divide an array into 'n' chunks?

Comment: Try Array.chunkBySize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Array.splitInto` function. E.g. splitting array into 3 chunks:

```
[|1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; |] |> Array.splitInto 3
```

Result:

```
[|
  [|1; 2; 3|]
  [|4; 5|]
  [|6; 7|]
|]
```

Note that you can calculate chunk size manually and use `Array.chunkBySize`. But then the last chuck can be much smaller than other chunks. E.g. in the sample above it will have only 1 item and it will be 3 times smaller than other chunks. `Array.splitInto` provides better distribution of items and doesn't require manual chunk size calculation.